# Время выполнения soap запроса в ZF2 и SoapUI

Tags: soap, zend-framework-2

При выполнении SOAP запроса из Zend Framework 2 получаю очень долго время ожидания:

```
$apiUrl = $this->_wsdlUrls[$this->_mode]['SessionCreateRQ'];
$options = Array (
  'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
  'cache_wsdl' => true,
);
$apiClient = new \Zend\Soap\Client ($apiUrl, $options);
$apiClient->setLocation($this->_actionUrls[$this->_mode]['SessionCreateRQ']);

file_put_contents (ZendRoot . '/public/task_logs/search.txt', "1-1. SessionCreateRQ start  " . date("h:i:s") . "\r\n", FILE_APPEND);
$session = $apiClient->SessionCreateRQ($data);
file_put_contents (ZendRoot . '/public/task_logs/search.txt', "1-2. SessionCreateRQ end  " . date("h:i:s") . "\r\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

В файл записан тайминг:

1-1. SessionCreateRQ start  07:17:15

1-2. SessionCreateRQ end  07:17:19

Время выполнения запроса выходит 4 с.

А при выполнении этого же запроса в SoapUI время выполнения получается в среднем 784 мс.

Почему время выполнения запроса в ZF2 выше в несколько раз, чем время выполнения через SoapUi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в том, что хоть и был включен кэш wsdl, однако прав на запись файла кэша в настроенную папку не хватало. После выдачи прав на запись на папку, кэш начал сохраняться и время ожидания ответа в ZF2 и SoapUI стало практически одинаковым.